# Red undelines on some devices with android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textEmailSubject"

Tags: android

I am using android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textEmailSubject" on some fields to prevent long lines from wrapping per a suggestion on a post here on Stackoverflow.  However I just noticed that on my Nexus-S (but not the Samsung Tab-2 7) some of the text is underlined in red.

For example "18 BR" has the BR undelined.  But "NAS2" is not underlined.  "TI" is underlined.  If I remove the android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textEmailSubject" then the underlines go away but the lines can wrap with long user names.

```
<!-- Readout Waypoint Name -->
<TextView
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textEmailSubject"
    android:id="@+id/textWaypoint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="--"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="@dimen/menu" />
```

What is the best way to solve this.  I can find nothing in Google or on Stackoverflow and have no idea what the best way to solve it is.

Comment: Means you want single line text of TextView?

Comment: Yes. I want a single line even if the input is longer.  I want it to truncate but show as much as the display can show.  In other words, I do not want word wrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `android:inputType` property and use below lines in your TextView to fix your problem

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: Thank you.  That both works with long lines without wrapping and does not have the red underlines.

Comment: The only change I made to fit what I wanted is to do "none" instead of "end" but that was easy to find once this answer put me on the right track.  Thanks again.

Comment: android:ellipsize="end" will indicate 3 dots(...) at the end of the text if your text is long and it is truncating due to not enough space. If you don't want to display dots then you can remove that line also. Also instead of this two line you can use `android:lines="1"` to make your textView single line.

Comment: Just to explain the lack of interest in ellips, my characters are an inch high and about 6 of them fit across the screen.  So, for example, if the text were "#2north" I can have "#2nort" or "#2n...".  The choice is clear.  I selected none because I got ... by default for some reason.